# How to access a database from a specific server using Java?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am trying to access a database from a different server , but no success so far. The event is, when I choose the `object` "ALL" in my `combobox`, the table will load all data from different servers.

The current code, which I only connected to the localhost, works fine. However, when I try to connect another server to load both of their data, I get a syntax error when trying to put `192.168.1.51.sales.items` in the `String sqlall`. Also, I tried modifying the `prepareStatement` by writing `cn.prepareStatement(sqlall) + cn1.prepareSatement("union Select * from 192.168.1.52.sales.items);` I have no more idea on how to connect on both servers.

I would like to apologize beforehand if you find my coding a bit messy. Thank you. My code is as follows:

```
 private void combobox_branchItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {  

  Object branch = combobox_branch.getSelectedItem();


    try
    {
        // All is selected
        if("All".equals(branch))
        {

          Connection cn = db.itemconnector.getConnection();


            String sqlall = " Select * from sales2.items union Select * from sales1.items union Select * from sales.items  " ;    //I tried accessing multiple databases in my own localhost and worked. 
            PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(sqlall);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            DefaultTableModel tm = (DefaultTableModel)itemTable.getModel();
            tm.setRowCount(0);
            while(rs.next())
            {
            Object o[] = {rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("location"), rs.getString("product_name"),rs.getString("product_category"),rs.getString("product_description"),rs.getInt("product_stock"), rs.getFloat("product_price"), rs.getString("product_status")};
            tm.addRow(o);


            }

        }

        catch (Exception e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e, "Connection Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }
    }
```

And I have a class in a different package and this is its code:

```
    package db;

    import java.sql.*;

     public class itemconnector {

    public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception
{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection cn = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.50:3306/sales","root","");

    return cn;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to query different databases **on different servers** in a single SQL query.

It is also not possible to get around this by "concatenating" prepared statements.  (For a start, that is nonsensical Java!)

You need to open a separate `Connection` to each separate database server and query the relevant tables on that server.  Then combine the information from the separate `ResultSet` objects in Java code.

The "combining" will be something like iterating the results in each result set and adding them to a Java data structure ...